# How to programmatically change Bottom Navigation View's Icons?

Tags: android, icons, bottomnavigationview

I want know how can I change Bottom Navigation View's Icons when user basically selects it and then again replace it with previous icon if user selects different option.

[image]
Below is my switch case snippet.

switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

```
            case R.id.ic_home:

                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();

                //menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.like_colored);

                break;

            case R.id.ic_connect:

                selectedFragment = new ConnectionFragment();

                break;

            case R.id.ic_add:

                selectedFragment = new AddPostFragment();

                break;

            case R.id.ic_noti:

                selectedFragment = new NotificationFragment();

                break;

            case R.id.ic_profile:

                selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();

                break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will change the icon and text color of a single menu item from anywhere (e.g. onResume). The code below works fine on 4.4.2 through (at least) Pie. It's bits and pieces from here and other similar threads. Some notes:

1. The menu item's icon is a drawable called "icon", but it doesn't work quite right to simply change that like I do the text color - sometimes the icon (if any) in the xml appears instead. This seems to always work.
2. It's written to be a static function so it's callable from multiple fragments; you could easily make it a member and strip out the activity argument in an activity class.
3. The drawable depends on whether it's a vector or a bitmap drawable for older APIs: bit map (and new API) code is a comment; newer APIs don't need the specific vector drawable function.

```
    static public void setMenuItemProperties(AppCompatActivity activity,
                                             MenuItem item,
                                             int resIconDrawable, int resColor) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        BottomNavigationItemView m = activity.findViewById(id);
        TextView t1 = m.findViewById(R.id.smallLabel);
        TextView t2 = m.findViewById(R.id.largeLabel);
        t1.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(resColor));
        t2.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(resColor));

        Drawable d = VectorDrawableCompat.create(activity.getResources(), resIconDrawable, null);
        //Drawable d = activity.getResources().getDrawable(resIconDrawable);
        item.setIcon(d);
    }
```

Call like this (from an Activity) to select between two icons and text colors for menu item 3. (`navigation` is the BottomNavigationView.)

```
      setMenuItemProperties(this, navigation.getMenu().getItem(3),
          enabled ? R.drawable.ic_settings_red_24dp : R.drawable.ic_settings_redish_24dp,
          enabled ? android.R.color.white : R.color.medium_dark_grey);
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want to do it programmatically do it by setting all menu items to default icons before the switch statement.

```
navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.defaultIcon1);
navigation.getMenu().getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.defaultIcon2);
navigation.getMenu().getItem(2).setIcon(R.drawable.defaultIcon3);
navigation.getMenu().getItem(3).setIcon(R.drawable.defaultIcon4);
navigation.getMenu().getItem(4).setIcon(R.drawable.defaultIcon5);
switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.ic_home:
                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
                break;
      case R.id.ic_connect:
                selectedFragment = new ConnectionFragment();
                menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.icon2);
                break;
      case R.id.ic_add:
                selectedFragment = new AddPostFragment();
                menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.icon3);
                break;
      case R.id.ic_noti:
                selectedFragment = new NotificationFragment();
                menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.icon4);
                break;
      case R.id.ic_profile:
                selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.icon5);
                break;
}
```

Or
You could do it by editing XML files instead of doing programmatically.

drawable/homeIconSelector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homeNormalIcon" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homeSelectedIcon" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

and your menu file
menu/(menunamehere).xml

```
<item
android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
android:icon="@drawable/homeIconSelector"
android:title="@string/title_child" />
```

Comment: this one is helpful , when using bottom navigation view for menu item.

Answer (score 2):

Let try this approach.
create an xml file in your drawable folder. For example, xml file name is home_selector.xml at drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/child" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/child_fill" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Now add home_selector in menu item of your bottom_navigation_main.xml 
Like: android:icon="@drawable/child_selector"
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_child"
    android:icon="@drawable/child_selector"
    android:title="@string/title_child" />

</menu>
```

Done, Give it a try. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bottom navigation with navigation component then it will help you ..

[navigation bar icon and color not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72137525/12748481)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change the menu bar icons, try this code

`BottomNavigationView navigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>Resource.Id.navigation); IMenu i=navigation.Menu;IMenuItem ii= i.FindItem(Resource.Id.navigation_home); ii.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.not_connected);`

Comment: Your code is missing some formatting.