# Change Icon of BottomNavigationView on Runtime

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-navigationview, material-components-android

I want to change the icon of my BottomNavigationView after it got initialized. If I do it at onCreate it works fine. But I have to do it after getting an asynchronous response from the server.

```
val menuItem = bottom_navigation.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_item_4)
menuItem.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_nav_message)
```

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496395/how-to-programmatically-change-bottom-navigation-views-icons

Comment: @Muhammad Farhan This doesnt work if you call it after the bottomNavigationView is already initialized

Answer (score 0):

this can give you the option to change the icon in runtime.

```
MenuItem logOut= nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logOut);
logOut.setIcon(*here you can give the path of your icon*);
```

Comment: It only works like that when i call it before the OnNavigationItemSelectListener gets initialized and my async call comes way later.