# BottomNavigationView with navigation component - selected fragment not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I'm currently migrating to android navigation component and cannot get the fragment transitions to work when a new item is being selected in the BottomNavigationView. I followed the instructions in the official documentation and I did not found any issues why the selected fragment is not being displayed.

In the activity in the onCreate method im setting the nav controller:

```java
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_main_layout_nav_host);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.includedAppbarMain.bottomNavigationViewMainAppbar, navController);
```

The layout contains the nav host fragment and the BottomNavigationView:

```xml
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_layout_nav_host"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/activity_main"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view_main_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_bottom_navigation" />
```

Menu for the BottomNavigationView:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_activity_main_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_24dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_activity_main_notebooks"
        android:title="Notebooks"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_24dp"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_activity_main_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"/>
</menu>
```

Navigation:

```xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/action_activity_main_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/action_activity_main_home"
        android:name="com.inknotes.view.fragment.MainHomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/main_vertical_navigation_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/action_activity_main_notebooks"
        android:name="com.inknotes.view.fragment.MainNotebookFragment"
        android:label="@string/main_vertical_navigation_notebooks"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_notebook" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/action_activity_main_search"
        android:name="com.inknotes.view.fragment.MainSearchFragment"
        android:label="@string/main_vertical_navigation_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_search" />
</navigation>
```

The ids of the menu items and fragments are also matching and i'm running out of ideas why the new fragment is not being displayed when i select another item in the BottomNavigationView.

### Edit 1:

I did some more testing and found out that popping the fragments from the backstack also does not work, maybe I have some generel issues with my nav controller?

### Edit 2:

MainActivity (I removed some stuff because it would be too long):

```java
@MainActivityScope
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ComponentCallbacks2, MainActivityHandler,
        SpeedDialView.OnActionSelectedListener, BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    // Static variables
    public static final String EXTRA_PATH = "com.inknotes.EXTRA_PATH";

    // Injected objects
    @Inject MainHomeFragment mainHomeFragment;
    @Inject MainFolderFragment mainFolderFragment;
    @Inject MainNotebookFragment mainNotebookFragment;
    @Inject MainSearchFragment mainSearchFragment;
    @Inject MainFolderAddDialog mainFolderAddDialog;
    @Inject MainNotebookAddDialog mainNotebookAddDialog;
    @Inject MainNotebookActionModeCallback mainNotebookActionModeCallback;
    @Inject MainFolderActionModeCallback mainFolderActionModeCallback;
    @Inject FileHelper fileHelper;
    @Inject ClipboardHelper clipboardHelper;
    @Inject ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;
    @Inject MainVerticalNavigationAdapter mainVerticalNavigationAdapter;
    @Inject XmlParser<OptionItem> xmlParser;

    // Objects
    public MainActivityComponent daggerMainActivityComponent;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private MainViewModel mainViewModel;
    private MainFolderViewModel mainFolderViewModel;
    private MainNotebookViewModel mainNotebookViewModel;
    private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;
    private MenuItem searchMenuItem;
    private SelectionTracker<Long> verticalNavigationSelectionTracker;
    private NavController navController;

    // Variables
    private boolean isBackPressed = false;

    // =============================================================================================
    //region Base methods

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
                this,
                R.layout.activity_main,
                new BindingComponent(this));
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        // Set the main dagger component
        daggerMainActivityComponent = ((InkNotesApplication) getApplication())
                .component()
                .mainActivityComponentFactory()
                .create(this);
        daggerMainActivityComponent.inject(this);

        // Get all viewModels
        mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel.class);
        mainFolderViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainFolderViewModel.class);
        mainNotebookViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainNotebookViewModel.class);

        // Set the default file
        mainViewModel.setDefaultFile(getExternalFilesDir("notes"));
        mainViewModel.setCurrentFile(getExternalFilesDir("notes"));

        gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureListener());

        // Set variables of binding
        binding.setHandler(this);
        binding.setViewModel(mainViewModel);

        // Setup main toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(binding.includedAppbarMain.materialToolbarMainAppbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_24dp);

        // Setup explorer toolbar
        binding.includedAppbarFolder.materialToolbarFolder.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this::onOptionsItemSelected);

        // Setup drawer and navigation layout
        binding.navigationViewMainFolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (binding.drawerLayoutMain != null) {
            binding.drawerLayoutMain.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            binding.drawerLayoutMain.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                    if (mainFolderActionModeCallback != null) {
                        mainFolderActionModeCallback.finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Setup navigation
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_main_layout_nav_host);
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            navController.getGraph()
        ).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        if (binding.includedAppbarMain.bottomNavigationViewMainAppbar != null) {
           NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.includedAppbarMain.bottomNavigationViewMainAppbar, navController);
        }

        // Set the explorer and file card fragment
        /*
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_layout_main_layout_fragment_container, mainHomeFragment).commit();*/
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_layout_main_folder_container, mainFolderFragment).commit();

        // Setup the floating action button
        binding.includedAppbarMain.speedDialViewMainAppbar.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_fab);
        binding.includedAppbarMain.speedDialViewMainAppbar.setOnActionSelectedListener(this);

        // Setup bottom navigation view
        if (binding.includedAppbarMain.bottomNavigationViewMainAppbar != null) {
            binding.includedAppbarMain.bottomNavigationViewMainAppbar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        // Setup the vertical navigation view
        if (binding.recyclerViewMainVerticalNavigation != null) {
            binding.recyclerViewMainVerticalNavigation.setAdapter(mainVerticalNavigationAdapter);
            List<OptionItem> items = xmlParser.parse(getResources().getXml(R.xml.menu_main_vertical_navigation), OptionItem.class);
            // Create the selection tracker
            // Add observer to the selection tracker
            mainVerticalNavigationAdapter.setSelectionTracker(verticalNavigationSelectionTracker);
            verticalNavigationSelectionTracker.select((long) R.id.action_activity_main_vertical_navigation_home);
            mainVerticalNavigationAdapter.submitList(items);

            binding.includedAppbarMain.speedDialViewMainAppbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            toggleFolderNavigationView(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (binding.drawerLayoutMain != null) {
            if (binding.drawerLayoutMain.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                binding.drawerLayoutMain.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        if (binding.drawerLayoutMain != null) {
            return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, binding.drawerLayoutMain);
        }
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        selectNavigationItem(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }
    //endregion

    // =============================================================================================
    //region Custom methods

    private void selectNavigationItem(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_activity_main_home:
            case R.id.action_activity_main_vertical_navigation_home:
                //navController.navigate(R.id.action_activity_main_home);

                if (binding.drawerLayoutMain != null) {
                    binding.drawerLayoutMain.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
                }
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                if (searchMenuItem != null) {
                    searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                }
                binding.includedAppbarMain.appBarLayoutMainAppbar.setExpanded(true);
                binding.includedAppbarMain.speedDialViewMainAppbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                toggleFolderNavigationView(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case R.id.action_activity_main_notebooks:
            case R.id.action_activity_main_vertical_navigation_notebooks:
                //navController.navigate(R.id.action_activity_main_notebooks);

                if (binding.drawerLayoutMain != null) {
                    binding.drawerLayoutMain.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                }
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                if (searchMenuItem != null) {
                    searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                }
                binding.includedAppbarMain.appBarLayoutMainAppbar.setExpanded(true);
                binding.includedAppbarMain.speedDialViewMainAppbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                toggleFolderNavigationView(View.GONE);
                break;
            case R.id.action_activity_main_search:
            case R.id.action_activity_main_vertical_navigation_search:
                //navController.navigate(R.id.action_activity_main_search);

                if (binding.drawerLayoutMain != null) {
                    binding.drawerLayoutMain.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
                }
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                if (searchMenuItem != null) {
                    searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
                }
                binding.includedAppbarMain.appBarLayoutMainAppbar.setExpanded(false);
                binding.includedAppbarMain.speedDialViewMainAppbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                toggleFolderNavigationView(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }
        isBackPressed = false;
    }
```

In the selectNavigationItem method you can also see that I tested to navigate manually with `navController.navigate(R.id.action_activity_main_notebooks);`, that worked but popping the backstack also didn't work. But setting the BottomNavigationView with `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.includedAppbarMain.bottomNavigationViewMainAppbar, navController);` should make it unnecessary to call navigate.

HomeFragment:

```java
@MainActivityScope
public class MainHomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public final static String NAME = "MainHomeFragment";

    @Inject
    public MainHomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_home, container, false);
    }
}
```

NotebookFragment:

```java
@MainActivityScope
public class MainNotebookFragment extends Fragment {
    // Static variables
    public final static String NAME = "MainNotebookFragment";
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";

    // Injected objects
    @Inject ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;
    @Inject MainNotebookAdapter mainNotebookAdapter;
    @Inject MainNotebookItemTouchHelperCallback mainNotebookItemTouchHelperCallback;

    // Objects
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MainNotebookViewModel mainNotebookViewModel;

    // Variables
    private int columnCount = 4;

    @Inject
    public MainNotebookFragment() {
    }

    // =============================================================================================
    //region Base methods

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            columnCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.column_count_portrait);
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            columnCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.column_count_landscape);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_notebook, container, false);

        ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).daggerMainActivityComponent.inject(this);
        mainNotebookViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), viewModelFactory).get(MainNotebookViewModel.class);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            columnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }

        // Set the mainNotebookAdapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (columnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount));
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mainNotebookAdapter);
        }

        // Set the item touch helper
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(mainNotebookItemTouchHelperCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mainNotebookViewModel.getItems().observe(
                getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                fileCardItems -> mainNotebookAdapter.setItems(fileCardItems)
        );

        mainNotebookViewModel.getSelectedItems().observe(
                getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                selectedExplorerItems -> mainNotebookAdapter.setSelectedItems(selectedExplorerItems)
        );

        mainNotebookViewModel.getQueryText().observe(
                getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                queryText -> mainNotebookAdapter.getFilter().filter(queryText)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(mainNotebookAdapter)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(mainNotebookAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(mainNotebookAdapter);
    }
    //endregion
}
```

SearchFragment:

```java
@MainActivityScope
public class MainSearchFragment extends Fragment {
    public final static String NAME = "MainSearchFragment";

    @Inject
    public MainSearchFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_search, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Timo, what the `includedAppbarMain` var refer to?

Comment: Hi Zain, I have split my layout into multiple files. So basically I have my `activity_main` layout that includes with the includes tag the `appbar_main` (so that what you have asked for) which contains the appbar, toolbar and bottomnavigatinview. Within that file im including the `layout_main` that contains the navhostfragment itself. So in short: `activity_main` -> `appbar_main` -> `layout_main`. And in case you want to ask, yes the condition `binding.includedAppbarMain.bottomNavigationViewMainAppbar != null` ist true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution, the problem was the `onNavigationItemSelected` function. So either removing those two parts from the MainActivity resolves the issue:

```java
if (binding.includedAppbarMain.bottomNavigationViewMainAppbar != null) {    
 binding.includedAppbarMain.bottomNavigationViewMainAppbar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
...
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    selectNavigationItem(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}
```

Or what I did, because I stil need the function, return `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)` instead of true.

```java
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    selectNavigationItem(item.getItemId());
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Finally got resolved my issue ,**
when i am using a nav graph where many fragment and actions occur for a bottom navigation component where only 5 menu available .

> my issue was when i am visit any menu then it show active stag but
> when i visit twise which is already visit then no active stag show ..
> Means that no active color showing after navigating fragment.

**Fixed with this solution :-**

> **app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
> app:popUpToInclusive="true"**

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/addAccountFragment"
        android:name="app.ph7.doctor.ui.screens.home.addAccount.AddAccountFragment"
        android:label="AddAccountFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_account">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addAccountFragment_to_accDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/accDetailsFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addAccountFragment_to_notificationFragment"
            app:destination="@id/notificationFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addAccountFragment_to_appointmentFragment"
            app:destination="@id/appointmentFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
```

> Here homefragment is startDestination

```
<navigation
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_navigation"
        app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">
```

Hope your problem resolved ..

Answer (score 0):

As official document says -

> NavController manages app navigation within a NavHost.
>
> Apps will generally obtain a controller directly from a host, or by
> using one of the utility methods on the Navigation class rather than
> create a controller directly.

When you are creating your navController, make sure you are assigning it the id of your navigation host fragment. This is how you are creating your navController.

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_main_layout); 
// issue here, use R.id.fragment_main_layout_nav_host
```

while the id of nav host fragment in your xml is -

```
<fragment>
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_layout_nav_host"
    .....
</fragment>
```

Make sure you are using same id.

Happy Coding !!

Comment: I updated my question, see comment in Zahins reply, anyway thanks for the reply.

Comment: is there any error message in logcat, when item is being selected in the BottomNavigationView ? If so, please post it

Comment: I checked logcat but unfortunately could not find any errors that occur when an item is being selected. Is there a specific tag I can serach for in logcat?

Comment: hmm well.. there not a specific tag as such. when item is being selected it just show a click with ripple effect in BottomNavigation, nothing else ? What happen if you try to go back or click back button ? does it produce any error ?

Comment: and please upload the rest of the code for your activity_main_home and activity_main_notebooks ...

Comment: Navigating back with the back button just closes the activity, so nothing is being added to the back stack. I updated my question with the rest of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong id of the host fragment when initializing the `NavController`

You need to replace

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_main_layout);
```

with

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_main_layout_nav_host);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just checked my code and the ids are matching, so that was just a mistake from my side while copying the code into the question, I'm sorry. I edited my question with the correct id.

Answer (score 0):

``Did you initialize BottomNavigationView

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView =binding.bottomNavigationAppBar
```

and call bottomNavigationView in

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView,
            navController);
```

Comment: I'm accessing the BottomNavigationView via databinding so the view is already initialized, ne need to do it again.

Comment: I faced the same issue. I had forced to use `findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)` instead of ViewBinding. Anyone have idea why this will happen?